I Want to remove duplicate data in google sheet including all it occurrences
This is the simple code which remove all the duplicate values and working fine.
function removeDuplicate2ndPhase() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hourly Data');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B3:M' + lastRow);
  
  range.removeDuplicates([3]);
}

all i want to remove duplicate data with it's original values too.
I filter data on the basis of column C and i tried this code it get the desired results but problem if i manually change a value in column C and all other row data is same still it delete that row. Which I don't want.
function keepUniqueValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hourly Data');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B3:M' + lastRow);
  
  // Get all values in the specified range
  var values = range.getValues();
  var uniqueCheck = {};
  var uniqueValues = [];
  
  // Loop through each row in the range
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var key = row[2]; // Assuming the third column (index 2) is the column to check for duplicates
    
    // Check if the key is already in uniqueCheck
    if (!uniqueCheck[key]) {
      uniqueCheck[key] = true;
      uniqueValues.push(row);
    } else {
      // If the key is already in uniqueCheck, remove it from uniqueValues (if it exists)
      var indexToRemove = uniqueValues.findIndex(function(existingRow) {
        return existingRow[2] === key; // Check if the existing row has the same key value
      });
      if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
        uniqueValues.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Clear existing data in the range
  range.clearContent();
  
  // Set the unique values back to the range
  if (uniqueValues.length > 0) {
    range.offset(0, 0, uniqueValues.length, uniqueValues[0].length).setValues(uniqueValues);
  }
}



function keepUniqueValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hourly Data');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B3:M' + lastRow);
  
  // Get all values in the specified range
  var values = range.getValues();
  var uniqueCheck = {};
  var uniqueValues = [];
  
  // Loop through each row in the range
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var key = row[2]; // Assuming the third column (index 2) is the column to check for duplicates
    
    // Check if the key is already in uniqueCheck
    if (!uniqueCheck[key]) {
      uniqueCheck[key] = true;
      uniqueValues.push(row);
    } else {
      // If the key is already in uniqueCheck, remove it from uniqueValues (if it exists)
      var indexToRemove = uniqueValues.findIndex(function(existingRow) {
        return existingRow[2] === key; // Check if the existing row has the same key value
      });
      if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
        uniqueValues.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Clear existing data in the range
  range.clearContent();
  
  // Set the unique values back to the range
  if (uniqueValues.length > 0) {
    range.offset(0, 0, uniqueValues.length, uniqueValues[0].length).setValues(uniqueValues);
  }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Use Array.map() and Array.filter(), like this:
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
'use strict';

function keepUniqueValues() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Hourly Data!B3:M');
  const uniques = getUniqueRows_(range.getValues(), 2);
  range.clearContent();
  if (uniques.length) {
    range.offset(0, 0, uniques.length, uniques[0].length).setValues(uniques);
  }
}

/**
* Gets rows where a key appears exactly once in a key column.
*
* @param {Object[][]} values The 2D array to filter.
* @param {Number} keyColumnIndex The zero-indexed key column index.
* @return {Object[][]} The rows where the key appears exactly once.
*/
function getUniqueRows_(values, keyColumnIndex) {
  const keys = values.map(row => row[keyColumnIndex]);
  const _count = (key) => keys.filter(k => String(k) && k === key).length;
  return values.filter(row => 1 === _count(row[keyColumnIndex]));
}

See Array.map() and Array.filter().
